# Reactjs trigger button with keydown when pressing space bar not on the button

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, reactjs

Right now, I'm trying to create a button that activates OnKeyDown, but that command only works when the user is hovering over the button and has selected it. Is there a way to use OnKeyDown so you can hover over an img on the other side of the screen, press space bar, and activate the button.
something like

```
render(){
return(
<div>

<button onKeyDown = {this.dostuff}/>
<img src = {thing}/>
</div>

);

}
```

Except when hovering over the image and pressing space the button is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `useEffect()` hook, similar to `componentDidMount()`, and by doing so you can add a global window event listener to your code in the `useEffect()` function once the component has mounted to the screen.

Code sample in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-payne-odgsz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Alright, thanks! Is this possible to do inside a class component?

Comment: `useEffect()` was created for **stateful functional components**, it is more of like an enhancement to the class components since it is considered syntactic sugar over functions, Plus during future development, the app logic will be distributed among `componentDidMount()` , `componentDidupdate()` , `componentWillUnmount()`. anyway, it is actually possible to do it inside the class component as I previously stated using `componentDidMount()` function. and I highly recommend you to use state hooks.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have an unrelated question if you're willing to answer it. Do you know how I can deploy a react-flask application onto AWS ec2?

Comment: You should avoid global event listeners because those can collide with expected behavior in other components. It's especially dangerous with the spacebar because it will override native functionality for things like buttons and checkboxes. I recommend scoping any listeners to elements in the component, or using [a library that handles it for you](https://github.com/JohannesKlauss/react-hotkeys-hook).